# How do I postion text in various areas inside a div element?

Tags: html

I imagine the solution to this is really simple but my brain is fried from todays work. Basically, how do I position text in various places around a div box, e.g. a word in the top left corner and another word in the bottom right? Thanks.

Comment: Probably: 1) Wrap the text into spans 2) Make the div `position: relative` 3) make the spans `position:absolute` and position them as required using `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right`.

Answer (score 1):

Place each text into a div/span/etc of its own and then position them as needed.  This is an example how:

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:5em;
  width: 50%;
}
.tl{
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  height:1em;
  border-color: #f00;
  width:auto;
}
.br{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  right:5px;
  height:1em;
  border-color: #0f0;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="tl">top left</div>
  <div class="br">bottom right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use label in the div or any other and make the css for each corner and apply that css to the label so you text can be placed accordingly